# Start another timer in Countdown timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I am having a problem seting pause when roundtime is finished. When User clicks the button it starts counting down timer and when finished text returns to its value as I want. But I want that another timer2 is started,when countdown (timer) is finished. Now it starts counting at the same time. Each timer has own textView on screen. 
Here is code:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long roundtime= Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(msg1))*1000; //User set Time for Round
            long pause= Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(msg2))*1000; //User set Time for Pause
            Counting timer = new Counting(roundtime, 1000); // class CountdownTimer
            Counting2 timer2 = new Counting2(pause, 1000); // class CountdownTimer

            timer.start(); // I want to start with this timer first
            timer2.start(); // And when timer is finished start with this in own textView
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E93E8.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html). It's literraly what you need. Just start one timer, and on that timer's `onFinish()` method , start the new timer. Something like:

```
CountDownTimer timer1 = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
//do whatever you need here, this gets called every 1000 milliseconds (the 2nd parameter
of the constructor, the first is total time in ms
 }

 public void onFinish() {
    CountDownTimer timer2 = new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        //same logic
        };
        timer2.start();
    }
};
```

`timer1.start();`

Comment: Hei Vucko! i now what you mean but I have two different countdown timer made because I have two textview for each timer separate on screen. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Not really, try and figure out this class, it's really good, I'm off to sleep now, will write to you tomorrow if you can't manage mate :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, you want something like this. As soon as your activity is started, something must happen after 'xx' seconds. Then there must be a pause of 'yy' seconds and then same thing must 'xx' seconds. right?

You can use `Handler.postDelayed()`

```
static boolean pause = false;

onCreate(){
    if (pause) {
        delay = xx + yy;
else
       delay = xx;


Handler.postdelay(new ... , delayTime);
```

and then obviously, make `pause = true` in innerclass of PostDelay

Comment: Rusheel: when the user clicks the button, countdown begins(10sec) and when is finished,another countdown begins(4sec). Can you see image I have updated?